# Can you use githooks on github.com?

Tags: github, githooks

I want to execute a script on „pre-merge” which checks commit message - it works well with git. But is there a possibility to use githooks on github.com, when squashing and merging to check commit message?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works with github also. explore this module https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli